# How to delete all partitions from iMac without an OS installed and rebuild a fusion drive without UUID

Tags: hard-drive, imac, partition, fusion-drive, uuid

a friend of mine bought a second hand iMac and they erased sort of everything from the iMac before it was given to him. There is no OS installed and it's not possible to instal a new version from OSX from Internet Recovery because the Hard Drive is greyed out. When I open terminal and check distil list this shows up: [image: Diskutil List]
What are those 17 disks? and how can I remove them and rebuild the whole harddrive? Everywhere I look they say that is should have an UUID but when I use diskutil cs list it says "No CoreStorage logical volume groups found".

iMac 27" early 2016
2TB Fusion
8GB Ram
Internet recovery (El Capitan)

I hope there is someone that can help me!

So this is actually my question. Can I delete everything there is on this harddrive and rebuild it al?

grts,

Alex

Comment: It may be easiest to take that hard drive and put it into another machine to format, partition and reinstall. Or, will it start in « disk mode » and you access / format etc it from another machine?

Comment: Do you mean Target Disk mode?

Comment: yes, and couldn’t think of the correct name - thanks! Have done the first method often, but not tried the second...